# windows 10, bat file, python PermissionError: [Errno 13]

Tags: python, git, batch-file

I create a bat file, `run_git.bat`, which was set to run automatically(by Task Scheduler Library), and it did be given admin privileges.

the contents of bat file are as follows

```
python F:\Dev\config_for_clash\code\_main.py 0 0
pause
move /y  erye.yaml F:\Dev\config_for_clash\config-for-clash\subscription || F:\Dev\config_for_clash\warn.bat && exit
pause
cd F:\Dev\config_for_clash\config-for-clash
git pull --rebase origin master
git add .
git commit -m "update subscription"
git push origin master
pause
exit
```

when it's finshed running, the python file `_main.py` will create file `erye.yaml`

if all goes well,`erye.yaml`will be upload to my github.

When I run `run_git.bat` manually, it does, but when the computer run it as set, it doesn't work out.

error message(from cmd consol) are as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Dev\config_for_clash\code\_main.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Dev\config_for_clash\code\_main.py", line 14, in main
    edit_manage(filename, nodes, nodes_names)
  File "F:\Dev\config_for_clash\code\write.py", line 58, in edit_manage
    with open(name+'.yaml', "a+", encoding="utf-8") as fyaml:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.\\erye.yaml'
```

Thanks for the reply

Comment: You should try to isolate the problem: try running each line alone in a batch file... Then try to build a minimal example of your problem... This way your question will also be useful to others that will come looking for a similar problem.

Comment: I did try and the error message are given above
i just don't know how to handle this issue

Comment: My guess: From the scheduler, the current directory is not writable for the python script. Try to add `cd F:\Dev\config_for_clash\config-for-clash` before the `python F:\Dev\config_for_clash\code\_main.py 0 0` line.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. The error message still exists

Comment: Does the file `erye.yaml` already exist? If it does, that could have something to do with your issue.

Comment: can you discribe it more exactly?
when it was run manually, that file was move to `F:\Dev\config_for_clash\config-for-clash\subscription`, and if it was run by task scheduler, it doesn't generate a file at all

Comment: When a scheduled task is set to run whether the user is logged on or not, the working directory is set to `C:\Windows\System32`. To change to a different drive and directory you need to use `CD /D`.  Your permissions problem is because it is trying to write to a protected directory.  I hope `F:` is a local drive letter and not a mapped network drive. If so you will need to work around that as well.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by add `/d`!